# Overriding 'text' in UILabel

Tags: variables, swift, properties, uilabel, overriding

Is there a way to do this? I thought it would be as simple as

```
override var text: String?
```

in a subclass of UILabel. However, this does not work. It shows an error: *Cannot override with a stored property 'text'*

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way or this is simply not possible? And if it is not possible, what's exactly causes it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Override to do what? Override the accessor methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redefine a property (var) from the superclass in your subclass. This was also true in obj-c, you could only redeclare read only properties to be read write. That's why you get an error.

So, instead, override the setter and getter functions and implement them to do what you want.